# Create several git branches in one go

Tags: git

If I am in master branch and want to create another branch named myAwesomeBranch but without checking out to it, I do:

```
git branch myAwesomeBranch
```

I would like to create several branches in one command from master, is that possible?

I tried with:

```
git branch myAwesomeBranch1 myAwesomeBranch2 myAwesomeBranch3
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I suppose there is always `for branch in myAwesomeBranch1 myAwesomeBranch2 myAwesomeBranch3; do git branch $branch; done`

Comment: a for loop indeed would work - though, not sure why this would ever be needed?

Comment: @Arcones No built-in way to do that, no. Scripting, as been advised, is the way.

Comment: @treyBake I am in QA phase and need to simulate some environment where my branch and two fellows are synchronized

Comment: @Arcones ah I see ... then yeah, you'll have to write a for loop to do what you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
image origin: https://www.lynda.com/Git-tutorials/Delete-local-remote-branches/664821/719158-4.html

---

Git doesn't support `git branch <multiple branches>`

the right way to do it is to use a shell script (single line will do it as well)

```
# loop over the branch list you wish to create
for branchName in {b1,b2,b3}; 

    # Create the branch
    do git branch $branchName; 

    # Set the upstream so you will be able to push the branch to the remote
    git branch --track $branchName origin/$branchName

done
```

Comment: `for branchName in b1 b2 b3` would suffice; brace expansion doesn't do anything useful here.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can create multiple branches in one line (with multiple commands), by using ";"

`git branch myAwesomeBranch1; git branch myAwesomeBranch2; git branch myAwesomeBranch3`

Comment: Thank you very much